# Angular Toggle State Is Not Correct

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

In my app, I have a grid where the user can push some columns by sliding their toggles. I only want that specific column to appear when it's respected toggle gets slid by the user. But now, if I slide any of the toggles, all the columns appear instead of the one that I want. Here is my code, what should I change to fix my problem?

HTML:

```html
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="togglePlannedParty()" class="mr-8">Yayınlanan Partiler</mat-slide-toggle>
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="toggleSalesQuota()" class="mr-8">Kota Yönetimi</mat-slide-toggle>
<mat-slide-toggle (change)="toggleActivePlan()" class="mr-8">Aktif Planlar</mat-slide-toggle>

<ng-container matColumnDef="IncludePlannedParty">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Yayınlanan Partiler </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
    <div>
      {{row.MaterialPlan?.IncludePlannedParty}}
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="IncludeSalesQuota">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Kota Yönetimi </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
    <div>
      {{row.MaterialPlan?.IncludeSalesQuota}}
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="IncludeActivePlan">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Aktif Planlar </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index">
    <div>
      {{row.MaterialPlan?.IncludeActivePlan}}
    </div>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

TypeScript:

```typescript
@Input() MaterialPlanId: number;


  private _materialPlanParameters: IMaterialPlanParameter[] = [];
  @Input()
  set MaterialPlanParameters(prm: IMaterialPlanParameter[]) {
    this._materialPlanParameters = prm;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.MaterialPlanParameters);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  get MaterialPlanParameters(): IMaterialPlanParameter[] {
    return this._materialPlanParameters;
  }

  private _materialPlan: IMaterialPlan = {};
  @Input()
  set MaterialPlan(prm: IMaterialPlan) {
    this._materialPlan = prm;
  }

  get MaterialPlan(): IMaterialPlan {
    return this._materialPlan;
  }
dataSource: MatTableDataSource<IMaterialPlanParameter>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild(ProductSelectionDialogComponent, { static: false }) child;



  constructor(
    private _dialog: MatDialog,
    private _productionService: ProductionService,
    private _messages: Messages
  ) {
    this.initializeGridColumns(); 
    _productionService.onGeoTypesChanged.subscribe(
      (response: IBasicModel[]) => {
          this.geoTypes = response;
      }
  );
    // this._productionService.getGeoTypes().then((response) => {
    //   this.geoTypes = response;
    // });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      CustomOrderQuantity: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(150),
      ]),
      AdditionalProductionQuantity: new FormControl("", [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(150),
      ]),
      IncludePlannedParty: new FormControl("", []),
      IncludeSalesQuota: new FormControl("", []),
      IncludeActivePlan: new FormControl("", []),
      IncludeRawMaterialProducts: new FormControl("", []),
    });
  }
initializeGridColumns() {
  this.displayedColumns = [
    'StockIntegrationCode',
    'ReceiptName',
    'PackagingTheoricYieldQuantity',
    'GeoType',
  ];

  let itemIndex = 0;
  if (this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty == true) {
    this.displayedColumns.push("IncludePlannedParty");
  } else {
    itemIndex = this.displayedColumns.indexOf("IncludePlannedParty");
    if (itemIndex > 0) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
  }

  if (this._materialPlan.IncludeSalesQuota == true) {
    this.displayedColumns.push("IncludeSalesQuota");
  } else {
    itemIndex = this.displayedColumns.indexOf("IncludeSalesQuota");
    if (itemIndex > 0) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
  }
  if (this._materialPlan.IncludeActivePlan == true) {
    this.displayedColumns.push("IncludeActivePlan");
  } else {
    itemIndex = this.displayedColumns.indexOf("IncludeActivePlan");
    if (itemIndex > 0) {
      this.displayedColumns.splice(itemIndex, 1);
    }
  }

  this.displayedColumns.push("Actions");
}

togglePlannedParty() {
  //this.includePlannedParty = !this.includePlannedParty;


  this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty = !this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty;

  if (this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty == true) {
    this.form.controls["IncludePlannedParty"].clearValidators();
    this.form.controls["IncludePlannedParty"].updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    this.form.controls["IncludePlannedParty"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  this.initializeGridColumns();
}

toggleSalesQuota() {
  //this.includeSalesQuota = !this.includeSalesQuota;
  this._materialPlan.IncludeSalesQuota = !this._materialPlan.IncludeSalesQuota;


  if (this._materialPlan.IncludeSalesQuota == true) {
    this.form.controls["IncludeSalesQuota"].clearValidators();
    this.form.controls["IncludeSalesQuota"].updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    this.form.controls["IncludeSalesQuota"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  this.initializeGridColumns();
}

toggleActivePlan() {

  this._materialPlan.IncludeActivePlan = !this._materialPlan.IncludeActivePlan;

  if (this._materialPlan.IncludeActivePlan == true) {
    this.form.controls["IncludeActivePlan"].clearValidators();
    this.form.controls["IncludeActivePlan"].updateValueAndValidity();
  } else {
    this.form.controls["IncludeActivePlan"].updateValueAndValidity();
  }

  this.initializeGridColumns();
}
```

Comment: Can you put your code on Stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by you seems to get the job done. It displays the columns always

```
'StockIntegrationCode','ReceiptName','PackagingTheoricYieldQuantity','GeoType','Actions'
```

Additional columns are added whenever you turn on their `mat-select-toggle`.

I think there is some additional code being run in your file which is forcing all the columns to be added or forcing the `_materialPlan` values to be set as `true`, I think that is missing from the snippet you shared above. Can you share the full snippet of HTML and TS, so we can debug it further, are you getting any console errors?

Comment: I have added additional code. Also, no I do not get any console errors.

Comment: I think the problem may lie in the @Input() that you are using to set _materialPlan, as I cannot see what value it is being set into ._materialPlan in the code below that you shared
 `@Input()
  set MaterialPlan(prm: IMaterialPlan) {
    this._materialPlan = prm;
  }`.
Try removing the Inputs where you set ._materialPlan and try only changing it when you toggle the mat-selects-toggle. If it works then most likely the problem lies there.

Comment: Or try adding a debug point in the chrome console to check what is the value when the code reaches the IF statements. (when you toggle them):
if (this._materialPlan.IncludePlannedParty == true) { }
if (this._materialPlan.IncludeSalesQuota == true) { }
if (this._materialPlan.IncludeActivePlan == true) { }

in all three functions.